Get latest values from a SCD dimension table
I have a requirement where I maintain type 2 SCD in my dimension table as below.
For example on day_1 the material code M-01 has a name mat_1_old - now the transactions on day_1 are mapped with dim_mat_master_id 1 for M-01. Now on day_2 the name for M-01 gets updated as mat_1_new and hence this is updated to is_current as true and the transaction on day_2 are mapped with dim_mat_master_id as 2.


Now if I am doing aggregation over mat_name (say for example) - on directly joining I would get aggregations for mat_1_old as well as mat_1_new as follows :
select dmm.material_name, sum(qty) as quantity
from fct_material_transaction fmt
join dim_material_master dmm on 
fmt.dim_mat_master_id = dmm.dim_mat_master_id
group by dmm.material_name

result
mat_1_new, 60
mat_1_old, 100

But I need aggregation based on latest mapping, how to do that?. Is below approach correct?
with transaction_det as (
  select dmm.material_code, fmt.qty from fct_material_transaction fmt
  join dim_material_master dmm on 
  fmt.dim_mat_master_id = dmm.dim_mat_master_id
)
select dmm.material_name, sum(qty) from transaction_det td join dim_mat_master dmm on 
td.material_code = dmm.material_code where dmm.is_current_rec
group by dmm.material_name

result
mat_1_new, 160


Hi - I think in your DIM table screenshot you have the IDs the wrong way round. 1 should be old and 2 should be new. In any case, if your SQL gives the correct result then it's the correct approach. If you have working SQL then I'm not sure what you are actually asking?

Please don't post data as images or links to images (see [ask] and reasons.

I just did a self join on the dimension table which is_current_rec and this is working perfectly.
